# Git commit not working with Emacs and Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, emacs

I'm running it in vagrant on ubuntu 14.04. It was working fine before but now it's not.

If I run `git commit` Emacs opens up, it's set as the default editor in `.gitconfig`, and contains a blank buffer. I type my message and save.

Git returns, `Commit aborted because of empty message`.

The strange thing is that in Emacs, before when I would commit, Emacs would contain a bunch of Git-related messages and the files which were changed etc and I'd just add to it on top. Now it's just blank.

Comment: Does Emacs come with built-in handling of `git commit`, or are you perhaps thinking of the `magit` package that can be added to Emacs?

Comment: I'm not thinking of any package. I don't know if it comes built in but its always worked until now.

Comment: Okay, I am a little confused, so three questions:
1. Is emacs installed in vagrant?
2. Is the .gitconfig in vagrant or on your system?
3. When you say it worked, was it on your system or vagrant?

Comment: It's all  in vagrant, Emacs is installed there, the .gitconfig is there as well and yea it used to work in Vagrant but for some reason today it stopped. I tried to do an apt-get update and dist-upgrade to make sure things were running the latest version but that didn't help.

Comment: FYI, the blank file or buffer that you're editing is obviously not the file that Git is reading. Hence, after you save and exit Emacs, Git sees no changes to the file it expected you to edit.

Comment: Yea that seems to be what's going on. I don't see why Emacs is opening a blank file instead of the commit file.

Answer (score 0):

The commit message editor will open up on the name of the file generated by the commit message. If you have another script set it may not be passing on the command-line arguments. If the message is unchanged or the editor returns a non-zero code, the git commit won't go ahead.

I'd expect the setting in `.gitconfig` is incorrect. If you remove that does it come up with a different editor? Have you tried setting the `GIT_EDITOR` or `EDITOR` environment variables instead?